# How to turn off numlock led without turning off numlock in Windows?

Tags: keyboard, numlock

My redgear keyboard has a very bright numlock, capslock  and scrolllock led.
How to turn it off, while keeping the keys active ?

I have used sharp keys and hot keys, but changing registry doesn't works, any other key is not working as numlock and vice versa.
These lights are really irritating at night, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Use dark but translucent tape or marker over the LED's to reduce brightness to an acceptable level. Yes, this is a *hardware* hack, and much easier than putting series resistors in each LED. Either that, or check the keyboard manual for control -- you won't get much help, if you don't specify the keyboard model.

Comment: In Linux dig into `/sys/class/leds/`, identify the right link, follow it and write `0` to the file named `brightness`. A straightforward solution is to write `0` to the file periodically. The question mentions registry, so I *guess* your OS is not Linux. Well, your loss. :) Seriously now: the question should specify your OS (e.g. as a tag), so we could possibly give you general software solutions; and the keyboard model, so we could possibly give you specific software and/or hardware solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the complex option of opening the keyboard and replacing the LED or adding circuitry to decrease the voltage going to it, or the simple option of covering over the LED with marker or tape.

Comment: I was trying to fig out a way to map numlock to some other key in registery editor, but since numlock is a special key it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Blackout stickers help cover the NumLock light (you can get them at Amazon); you could also use duct or black electrical tape.